# Named parameters in Hibernate Type Double ignores decimals

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 4.2.2 and trying to make a sql query like this with double named values:

```
String queryString= "Select * from table where decimalValue=:myDecimal";
```

then i use

```
Query query = sesion.createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.setDouble(":myDecimal", -34.4865);
```

When i execute the query with query.list(); the ":mydecimal"variable is replaced with the value -34 deleting the decimals.

Comment: Make sure your column in entity is defined as `@Column(name = "COLMUN_NAME", precision = 2, scale = 4)` private BigDecimal   decimalValue;

Comment: There is no entity en java. Its just a fixed query on the fly